# Изменить выделение в UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

При нажатии на строку в *UITableView* строка выделяется и подсвечивается. Какие есть альтернативы этому функционалу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понятен ваш вопрос. О каких альтернативах идет речь? Но попробую ответить.

Во первых при нажатии на ячейку таблицы может быть инфицировано выделение, это то что вы назвали подсвечиванием.

## Какие могут быть опции у выделения?

- Выделение может быть отключено полностью. При этом не будет происходить подсвечивание, но вы не сможете обрабатывать нажатие на ячейку методом `selectRowAtIndexPath`.
- (**вариант по умолчанию**)Выделение может быть включено для одной ячейки - **single selection**. При нажатии на ячейку она подсвечивается, повторное нажатие снимает выделение, нажатие на другую ячейку делает выделенной ее, а предыдущая перестает быть выделенной.
- Выделение может быть включено для нескольких ячеек - **multiple selection**. Аналогично single selection, за тем исключением, что выделять можно несколько ячеек одновременно.

## Что делать с практической точки зрения?

- **Обработка нажатия**. Используя метод `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` можно произвести некое действие при нажатие на ячейку. Например переход на другой контроллер. необходимо иметь ввиду, что после действия ячейка остается выделенной. Если логика вашего приложения не предусматривает этого, то выделении лучше снять методом `deselectRowAtIndexPath`. Кстати так же можно обрабатывать и **потерю выделения** - `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath.
- **Простая подсветка**. При выделении ячейки, она переходит в соответствующее состояние и для ее оформления применяются специальные стили. Их можно задать свойствами ячейки - `selectedBackgroundView`, `multipleSelectionBackgroundView`, `selectionStyle`. Стоит упомянуть, что **ячейка может быть** не выделена (selected), но **подсвечена** (highlighted). В этом состоянии к ней так же применяются специальные стили, но вызов обработчика выделения не происходит и как выделенная она не помечается.
- **Групповые действия** Ко всем выделенным ячейкам можно обратится с помощью метода `indexPathsForSelectedRows`. Эти ячейки можно удалить, скрыть, передать на другой контроллер или на сервер.

Очень рекомендую ознакомится с официальной документацией:

- [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForCell:)
- [UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)UITableViewCell)
- [NSIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)NSIndexPath)

Answer (score 1):

1) Можно убрать подсветку при выделении на конкретных ячейках:

```
// вызывая метод:
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

// или по property:
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

2) Можно также полностью отключить выделение в самой таблице:

```
tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
```

Или задать параметр в Interface Builder'e:

[image: Скрин]

2) Можно добавить множественное выделение. Там же в Interface Builder'e или кодом:

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

Обратите внимание, что эти две строки включают множественное выделение:

```
tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

Но если их поменять местами, то выделение будет полностью отключено.

<sub>Использованы [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1166670/5308802) и [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/191245/5308802) ответы.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

сделай свои вьюшки для фона и подсвеченного фона:
cell.backgroundView = redView;
cell.selectedBackgroundView = greenView;

Также можно добавить свою label для текста, тогда родная подсветка не будет ее менять.